# Which tense is being used in 'it is moved from location A to B'?

Tags: tense, passive-voice

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> It is moved from location A to B.

If yes, then which tense is being used here? I'm not sure if a past tense can be followed by *is*.

Comment: I think it should be *It has moved* or *It has been moved*.

Comment: @DreamEater It appears so. If it is the case, then this would be a present perfect. If you were to make it past form, this would become a past perfect (if the assumptions are correct of course).

Comment: For past-tense, a simple *It moved* is perfect?

Comment: I disagree with these comments.  I agree with Mistu4u's answer.  A passive clause can be formed using a past participle, but that doesn't make it *past*, nor does it make it *perfect*.

Comment: @snailplane Upvoted and agreed. I speculated on my part that the OP wanted an explanation on a different sentence construction and elaborated on that... Wrongly. This is made all the more stupid on my part because in Dutch you ARE allowed to use the verb "to be" in present perfect form, for Dutch and English have very similar grammar rules.

Comment: This is in the present tense: *is* is always present tense in English.

Answer (score 12):

The sentence is purely grammatical. It is in [passive voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice). The sentence is:

> It is moved from location A to B *by somebody*.

*By somebody* is implicit in this sentence. So if I change it into [active voice](http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/active-passive-voice.aspx), it becomes:

> Somebody moves it from location A to B.

According the rule of voice change, if the active voice is in simple present, the passive voice changes into the following construction:

> Active voice: *John makes a cup of tea*. --> Passive voice: *A cup of
>   tea is made by John*.

You can check out the voice conversion rules on [STUDYANDEXAM.COM (Passive Voice for All Tenses Rules)](http://www.studyandexam.com/passive-voice-for-tense.html)

Comment: +1 I've added a long Supplement; if you would like to incorporate any or all of it in your answer I will be happy to delete it.

Comment: @StoneyB, Honestly I could have added those, but was too lazy to type all those, so instead added a link. What you have done is really worth some prize, let the upvotes play the role here, SE makers expected it to be i.e. better answers will get more upvotes. Let your answer garner more upvotes. :)

Comment: @StoneyB, Albeit I have seen practices where supplements like you added as an answer is edited into the already posted answer unless instead of being supplement they are complete answer to the question.

Comment: Question, wouldn't the passive sentence be: 'It was moved from location A to B by somebody', since it was done in the past?

Comment: @EnglishLearner, There is no proof it happened in past, but it can be in simple present, So the passive voice construction makes sense here.

Comment: The present passive is fairly rare in English. If you are talking about something that only happens once, you would probably say "it is being moved from A to B". However, you could say "whenever a bin at A becomes full, it is moved from A to B".

Comment: Passive voice is not a tense.

Comment: @tchrist, The OP while asking did not know about that.

Answer (score 7):

SUPPLEMENTAL to Mistu4u's ANSWER :

---

OP appears to be confused by the form *moved*. In this case the form does not represent a *past tense* but a *past participle*. In regular (weak) verbs, the two forms are identical, but they are used differently:

- if the form **heads** the verb phrase, it is a tense and expresses completed past action. In the case of *MOVE* that action may be either transitive or intransitive:

  > He **moved** it from A to B. (*transitive: **it** is the Direct Object and is the Patient of the action, acted upon by **he**, who is both Subject of the sentence and Agent of the action*)
  >   He **moved** from A to B. (*intransitive: **He**, Subject and Agent, acts, but not upon another person or object*)
- if the form **follows** a form of *BE* or *HAVE*, it is a past participle:

  - if it follows a form of *HAVE*, the construction is *perfect*, designating a past action with relevance at the time expressed by the form of *HAVE*. *MOVE* may be either transitive or intransitive:

    > He **has moved** it from A to B. (*transitive, present perfect: the action was in the past but is still relevant in the present*)
    >   He **had moved** from A to B by 1964. (*intransitive, past perfect: the action took place before 1964 but was still relevant in 1964*
  - if the form follows a form of *BE*, the construction is *passive*; the Subject of the construction is the Patient of the action, and the Agent is either not specified or is specified in a separate phrase. In this case *MOVE* can only be used in a transitive sense.

    > This is the case involved in OP's question and Mistu4u's answer.
  - Note that it is possible for *moved* to be preceded by *both* a form of *HAVE* and a form of *BE*, creating a *perfect passive* construction. In this case it is *HAVE* which is inflected for person and tense, and the *past participle* of *BE* is employed: *been*.

    > It **has been moved** from A to B.

Comment: Now that it's CW, do you mind if I reinstate my upvote?

Comment: @snailplane As long as it's not pulling votes from Mistu4u's answer, which is directly responsive, as this is not.